# Closure of a set A, Cl(A), is closed

Tags: general-topology

Definitions according to my book

def 1: $A$ is closed if every $x \notin A$ is an exterior point.

def 2: a point $x$ is exterior to $A$ if $\exists$ a neighborhood $N$ such that $N \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A$

def 3: a point $x$ is interior to $A$ if $\exists$ a neighborhood $N$ such that $N \subseteq  A$

def 4: Cl(A) = $\partial A \cup A$

So, using these  definitions only, say $Cl(A)$ is not closed, therefore $\exists$ $x \notin Cl(A)$ such that $x$ is NOT exterior to $Cl(A)$.
Now, if $x$ is interior, then there exists a neigborhood $N$ such that $x \in N \subseteq Cl(A)$. contradiction.

if $x$ is a boundary point, then $ x \in \partial A \subseteq  \partial A \cup A = Cl(A)$ again a contradiction.

Therefore, $x$ must be exterior, which contradicts assumption. Hence, Cl(A) is closed.

Is this solution to the problem correct? any feedback? thanks

Comment: def 4: $Cl(A)=\partial A\cup A$.

Comment: I find your constant pursuit of contradictions unsettling. How do you define $\partial A$?

Comment: $x \in \partial A$ if $x$ is a limit point of $A$ and every nghbd of $x$ contains a point $y \notin A$

Comment: @Citizen Maybe you can translate that as "for each nbhd $N$ of $x$, $\hat N\cap A$ and $\hat N\cap (X\setminus A)$ are non empty", where $\hat N=N\setminus \{x\}$. Thus, $x$ is in the boundary of $A$ if every nbhd of $A$ contains both interior and exterior points of $A$ different from $x$ itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already proven that a set is closed if, and only if $\partial A\subseteq A$. You have defined $\overline A=A\cup\partial A$. First prove that $$\tag 1 \partial(A\cup B)\subseteq \partial A\cup\partial B$$ $$\tag 2 \partial\partial A\subseteq\partial A$$

Then note that $\partial \overline A=\partial(A\cup\partial A)\subseteq\partial A\cup\partial\partial A\subseteq\partial A\subseteq \partial A\cup A=\overline A$.

*Proofs of $(1)$ and $(2)$*.

$(1)$ Suppose that $x\in \partial(A\cup B)$. Then for each nbhd $N$ of $x$, $N$ is not disjoint from $A\cup B$ neither from $X\smallsetminus (A\cup B)=(X\smallsetminus A)\cap (X\smallsetminus B)$. Thus, $N$ is not disjoint from neither $X\smallsetminus A$ nor $X\smallsetminus B$ and at least one of $A$ or $B$, so $x\in \partial A\cup\partial B$.

$(2)$ We prove $\partial A$ is closed. If $x\notin \partial A$ then there exists a nbhd $N$ of $x$ disjoint from $A$ or $X\setminus A$. But if $y$ is any point in $N$, then $N$ itself is a nbhd of $y$ disjoint from  $A$ or $X\setminus A$ and $y\notin \partial A$. Thus, $\partial A$ is closed, and $\partial\partial A\subseteq \partial A$.

Comment: I like this proof. It is better than mine, but I would like to know if mine is correct or not. Can you give me some feedback?

Comment: How can you show $\partial \partial A \subseteq \partial A$ ?